# Mouse click event firing multiple times

Tags: mouse, events

I have had terrible problems copying text and generally anything that makes use of the "Mouse Move" Event for weeks.

This thread has helped identify the problem but it does not have any suggestions for a fix
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2423022

Basically when I click the mouse it fires the Press and Release Events multiple times, and then when I release the mouse it fires the Release event once as it should.

Because the Release event is being fired multiple times upon press of the mouse it confuses any code that makes use of the move event.

When I single click on the title bar of any windows it often (but not always) maximises the window to full screen.

All the mice I own are USB - various models of HP. The mice all work fine on my daughter's Windows 10 computer, but play up on my Ubuntu 22.04 HP Elitebook 840 G1, I don't have any other computers to try them on.

It is very un-predictable, there is no consistency at all, it works fine for 10 minutes, and then plays up for a few minutes, as if it's something to do with processor demand that causes it to fire multiple events.

Edit:
The problem appears to be in the HP docking station, if i plug the mice into the USB port of the computer it seems to be working fine, but any of the 4 USB ports on the dock and it gives me problems. All I can assume is that inside the docking station is a USB splitter hub that has something wrong with it.

[image]

Comment: How is the mouse connected and is each mouse you have tried connected the same way?

Comment: they are all USB, infarct they are all varies models of HP optical mice, thanks

Comment: Do you have another USB port you can use to rule out it is a fault in that port.

Comment: i will try a different port, i wont know for a few hours if it makes any difference as its an intermittent problem

Comment: "and they all work fine on other computers" using the same OS? Which OS distro and version are you using? Please [edit] your question accordingly - don't add to the comment trail.